# What is the difference between build and new on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between build and new command on Rails?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

new is for a new instance of a specific model:

```
foo = Foo.new
```

build is for creating a new instance within an AR association:

```
bar = foo.build_bar  # (has_one or belongs_to)
```

or

```
bar = foo.bars.build # (has\_many, habtm or has_many :through)
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

**Update**

Per @toklands's suggestion, build and new are aliases as defined in [ActiveRecord::Relation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/959fb8ea651fa6638aaa7caced20d921ca2ea5c1/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L84):

So if class Foo has_many Bars, the following have identical effects:

- `foo.bars.new` <=> `foo.bars.build`
- `Bar.where(:foo_id=>foo.id).new` <=> `Bar.where(:foo_id=>foo.id).build`

And if `!foo.new_record?`

- `foo.bars.new` <=> `Bar.where(:foo_id=>foo.id).new`

Comment: indeed, but there's one thing missing: the difference (or the equivalence) of foo.bars.build and foo.bars.new.

Comment: Looks like there is not difference from in Rails  >3.2.6 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954313/build-vs-new-in-rails-3

Comment: can you separate out your old answer and the new updated answer, and maybe specify versions? Currently, it reads like you said one thing, and then contradict yourself without any clear notice of overriding or obsolescence.

Answer (score 23):

New and build are same as per the documentation
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb

Answer (score 3):

Prior to rails 2.2, you needed build for the has_many/has_and_belongs_to_many part of the relation in order for the new record to automatically have it's foreign keys set. For example:

```
user.timesheets.build
```

would set the foreign key. I think for rails 2.2 and onwards, new and build do the same thing for has_many and has_and_belongs_to_many relations.

Answer (score 2):

There was a time when build populated the caller with the new instance but new didn't. Right now from Rails 4 both new and build populate the caller with the new instance. Just play around in the console if you want to get an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I observed a difference between .build and .new when using them to create a 'dummy' object for a view form, using a using nested resource.

.build creates a parent_id
.new does not

Nested Resource example:
@list.items (where Item is nested under List)

@list.items.build 
...produces an object with all nil values EXCEPT for list_id.

Item.new creates a new item object, with all nil values.

It showed up in my 'show' page when iterating over @list.items
Not an issue until I needed @list.items further down same 'show' page in another form, where iteration on @list.items exposed the item (the one produced by .build) that had an associated list_id, but nothing else.

### Some sample outputs below...

@list.items.build 
=> #

---

2.2.3 :002 >   Item.all.build
 => #

---

2.2.3 :003 > Item.new
 => # 
2.2.3 :004 >