# Build vs new in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

In the Rails 3 [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), the `build` method for associations is described as being the same as the `new` method, but with the automatic assignment of the foreign key. Straight from the docs:

```
Firm#clients.build (similar to Client.new("firm_id" => id))
```

I've read similar elsewhere.

However, when I use `new` (e.g. `some_firm.clients.new` without any parameters), the new client's `firm_id` association **is** automatically created. I'm staring at the results right now in the console!

Am I missing something? Are the docs a bit out of date (unlikely)? What's the difference between `build` and `new`?

Comment: People looking for a quick answer, check the 2nd one down: "build" is just an alias for "new"

Answer (score 210, accepted):

You're misreading the docs slightly. `some_firm.client.new` is creating a new `Client` object from the clients collection, and so it can automatically set the `firm_id` to `some_firm.id`, whereas the docs are calling `Client.new` which has no knowledge of any Firm's id at all, so it needs the `firm_id` passed to it.

The only difference between `some_firm.clients.new` and `some_firm.clients.build` seems to be that `build` also adds the newly-created client to the `clients` collection:

```rb
(some_firm = Firm.new).save # Create and save a new Firm
#=> true

some_firm.clients           # No clients yet
#=> []

some_firm.clients.new       # Create a new client
#=> #<Client id: nil, firm_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

some_firm.clients           # Still no clients
#=> []

some_firm.clients.build     # Create a new client with build
#=> #<Client id: nil, firm_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

some_firm.clients           # New client is added to clients
#=> [#<Client id: nil, firm_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]

some_firm.save
#=> true

some_firm.clients           # Saving firm also saves the attached client
#=> [#<Client id: 1, firm_id: 1, created_at: "2011-02-11 00:18:47", updated_at: "2011-02-11 00:18:47">]
```

If you're creating an object through an association, `build` should be preferred over `new` as build keeps your in-memory object, `some_firm` (in this case) in a consistent state even before any objects have been saved to the database.

Comment: Using `some_firm.client.new` also adds the client to `some_firm.clients`, and calling `save` on `some_firm` resulted in a validation error indicating that `client` was invalid. If both `new` and `build` add the new client to `some_firm`'s client collection, what does `build` do that `new` doesn't do? I'm sorry for being dense, here!

Comment: I've added an example to my post to be more clear about the difference between `build` and `new`. As for the validation error, I'm guessing that your client model needs more data before it can be saved (e.g. a name field that can't be nil)? In which case, you'd still have to set the attributes before saving.

Comment: Thank you for those details. I am staring at different behavior right now, though I'm still on 3.0.3 (I'll update and check again in a moment). On `r:004`, `clients` for you is an empty collection; for me, it contains the `new` client. Pan Thomakos described the same behavior. And the validation error for the user said: `{:clients=>["is invalid"]}`

Comment: +1 I received your result with 3.0.4. I'd love if someone with 3.0.3 could confirm I'm not crazy.

Comment: @ClosureCowboy I tried to reproduce what you're seeing with 3.0.3, but I'm still getting the same behaviour as 3.0.4 (and 2.3.4). The only thing I can think of is that somehow your association classes have been patched, but I don't know how you'd figure out if that's the case or not.

Comment: @henrym It looks like in 3.2.6 clients.new and clients.build are similar in they both add the new object into the collection. I wanted to add a comment for anyone who came across this while Googling like I did

Comment: Looks like there is no difference between them in Rails 3.2.3

Comment: it's really crazy in rails 3.2

Comment: This answer is not correct for Rails >3.2.13, where 'build' is just an alias for 'new'. See @HatemMahmoud's answer below.

Comment: @henrym @hubbard @andreas This is only true of some associations/relations. Singular associations, for example, have entirely different definitions for `build` and `build_#{association}`. See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb#L28) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/singular_association.rb#L17).

Answer (score 95):

[`build`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L74) is just an alias for `new`:

```
alias build new
```

Full code can be found: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L74

Comment: `alias build new` as of rails 3.2.13

Comment: This is only true of some associations/relations. Singular associations, for example, have entirely different definitions for `build` and `build_#{association}`. See [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb#L28) and [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/builder/singular_association.rb#L17).

Comment: Is this still true for `Rails 4`?

Comment: [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9167#issuecomment-52789407) is the bug report... which suggests if you were using new like restaurant.customers.new, as a way of getting a new customer associated to restaurant without appending it to restaurant.customers, to use scoped... such as restaurant.customers.scoped.new

Answer (score 11):

You are correct, the build and new functions have the same effect of setting the foreign key, when they are called through an association. I believe the reason the documentation is written like this is to clarify that a new Client object is being instantiated, as opposed to a new active record relationship. This is the same effect that calling .new on a class would have in Ruby. That is to say that the documentation is clarifying that calling build on an association is the same is creating a new object (calling .new) and passing the foreign keys to that object. These commands are all equivalent:

```
Firm.first.clients.build
Firm.first.clients.new
Client.new(:firm_id => Firm.first.id)
```

I believe the reason .build exists is that Firm.first.clients.new might be interpreted to mean that you are creating a new has_many relationship object, rather than an actual client, so calling .build is a way of clarifying this.

Comment: So they *are* equivalent. That's definitely what it seems. Thank you!

Comment: This is not correct. The first two are equivalent in later versions of Rails (looks like at time of posting they were not). BUT, the last one has a significant difference in that Firm.first.clients will not contain the new client.

Answer (score 4):

`build` vs `new`:

> mostly new and build are same but **build stores object in memory**,

eg:

for new:

```
Client.new(:firm_id=>Firm.first.id)
```

For build:

```
Firm.first.clients.build
```

Here clients are stored in memory, when save firm , associated records are also saved.

Answer (score 2):

## Model.new

`Tag.new post_id: 1` will instantiate a Tag with its `post_id` set.

## @model.models.new

`@post.tags.build` does the same **AND** the instantiated Tag will be in `@post.tags` even before it's saved.

This means `@post.save` will save both the @post and the newly built tag (assuming :inverse_of is set). This is great because Rails will validate both objects before saving, and neither will be saved if either one of them fails validation.

## models.new vs models.build

`@post.tags.build` and `@post.tags.new` are equivalent (at least since Rails 3.2).

Comment: how about this `The only difference between some_firm.clients.new and some_firm.clients.build seems to be that build also adds the newly-created client to the clients collection:`?