# Post belongs to Topic and User. How do I create a Post with :topic_id and :user_id without exposing either with attr_accessible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm making a conventional forum to learn/practice Rails. As you're familiar with, Users can create Topics and Posts. Topics and Posts belong to the User that created them, and Posts belong to the Topic they were posted in. Note: Post is a nested resource of Topic.

```
User Model
  has_many :topics
  has_many :posts

Topic Model
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user

Post Model
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :topic
```

So, when a User creates a new Post, the Post needs a `user_id` and a `topic_id`.

I know about scoping associations with:

```
@user.posts.create(:title => "My Topic.")
@topic.posts.create(:content => "My Post.")
```

But those examples only set `user_id` and `topic_id` respectively, not both.

**My Question**

How can I do something like this:

```
@topic.posts.create(:content => "This is Dan's post", :user_id => @dan.id)
```

Without having to expose `user_id` in the Post model via `attr_accessible :user_id`?

In other words, I don't want to have to explicitly define `:user_id`.

I tried things like:

```
dans_post = @user.posts.new(:content => "the content of my post")
@topic.posts.create(dans_post)
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `build` for building associations, instead of `new`, as it will define the foreign key correctly. To solve your problem, use `merge` to merge in the user to the parameters for the post:

```
@topic.posts.build(params[:post].merge(:user => current_user))
```

Comment: `.new` builds foreign keys in Rails 3. I did find a pretty good [explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954313/build-vs-new-in-rails-3) of the difference between `new` and `build` on associations, though. `.merge(:user => current_user)` expects `:user_id` to be exposed by `attr_accessible` while `@post.creator = current_user` does not. I guess I can live with having to specify @post.creator on a second line.

Comment: @Ryan Bigg How to create post for a user from api? i gave as below current_user.posts.build(:params[:content]) but its showing user_id cant be blank in rails3

Comment: @Jasmine: Don't `validate_presence_of :user_id`. That's what is causing this problem.