# Rails 3 ActiveRecord API: .build method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am fairly new to Ruby/RoR (outside of a year) and I have noticed that there are several different methods inside of RoR or Ruby that basically do the same thing. The one method I am wanting to get some sort of clarification on, is the `.build` method. when it is effective to use or how to use it in its best light, sorta thing.

Thanks!

Comment: Build method where? ActiveRecord associations?

Comment: Is it simply just a collection of items associated to the instantiated model? For ex: `Firm.clients.build(1)`... this would return all clients associated to the `Firm where firm_id = 1`

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954313/build-vs-new-in-rails-3

Answer (score 5):

The .build method is an ActiveRecord method which is used to create a new record based on the has_many relationship in your model.

So lets say;

```
User has_many tweets
```

Then you can use

```
user.tweets.build(tweet_id)
```

This will create a new tweet in the tweets table associated with that user. It will also return that object too.

You probably want to put a params tweet_id in you argument depending on how you are implementing the app. :)