# Partial rendering one time too many for collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Creating a simple blog application,

I have this partial

```
.comment
%p
    %b 
        Namn:
        = comment.name

%p
    %b
        kommentar:
        = comment.content


%p
    = link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.post, comment],
            :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
            :method => :delete
```

and its called from

```
= render :partial => 'comment', :collection => @post.comments
```

it always renders the partial one time to many?

edit:

It has this form

```
= form_for ([@post,@post.comments.build])
```

Comment: Do you have something like @post.comments.build in your controller action, or in a form within the view?

Comment: Yes when I look at it now within the "calling" view I have form_for([@post, @post.comments.build])

Comment: Make that form_for([@post, @post.comments.new]) and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As depicted in the comments of your question, the `@post.comments.build` is the culprit. Change it to

```
= form_for ([@post, @post.comments.new])
```

and the additional item when rendering the collection should be gone.

There is a good post about the difference of build and new here: [Build vs new in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954313/build-vs-new-in-rails-3)

Comment: Collection still renders one empty one for me, even with this change.