# Comments form above comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i have a comments form above the comments themselves.

Works

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@post.comments.each do |comment|
  comment.id
end
@post.comments.build
  # form here
end
```

Desired but fails

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@post.comments.build
  # form here
end
@post.comments.each do |comment|
  comment.id
end
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954313/build-vs-new-in-rails-3

Answer (score 1):

controller

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@comment = @post.comment.new
```

view

```
form_for @comment do |f|
  ...
end

@post.comments.each do |comment|
  comment.id
end
```