# A confusion with an array object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have the following in my view. And I'm trying to figure out why this is happneing:

```
<% unless @question.answers.empty? %>
  <% @question.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <%= render :partial => '/answers/answer', :locals => { :question => @question, :answer => answer } %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

problem: `@question.answers.empty?` returns `false` when it should be `true`. It has some null `answer` object, and `@question.answers.length` returns `1` instead of `0`

Example: `[#<Answer id: nil, body: nil, user_id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, question_id: 18>]`

However, what's more confusing is, when I do it in console, @question.answers.empty? returns true and the length is 0 as it should be. Why is this happening?

```
1.9.3-p327 :001 > question = Question.find(18)
  Question Load (12.2ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 18]]
 => #<Question id: 18, body: "sddd", user_id: 7, created_at: "2013-01-25 01:47:06", updated_at: "2013-01-25 01:47:06"> 
1.9.3-p327 :002 > question.answers.length
  Answer Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = 18
 => 0 
1.9.3-p327 :003 > question.answers
 => []
```

Additionally, the particular question's length shows 0 on the index page and 1 on the show page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have something in your controller along the lines of this:

```
@answer = @question.answers.build
```

This is creating an object for a new answer and adding it to the `@question.answers` object. You might want to try `.new` instead of `.build`, that way it doesn't get included locally in `@question.answers`. See [Build vs new in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954313/build-vs-new-in-rails-3)

Comment: This is something I would've never caught by myself. Thank you so much.