# params.require().permit does not work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have this controller

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @person = Person.new
        @person.phones.new
    end

    # this is the action that gets called by the form
    def create
        render text: person_params.inspect
#       @person = Person.new(person_params)
#       @person.save

#       redirect_to people_path
    end

    def index
        @person = Person.all
    end

private

    def person_params
        params.require(:person).permit(:name, phones_attributes: [ :id, :phone_number ])
    end

end
```

and this view

```
<%= form_for :person, url: people_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <%= f.fields_for :phones do |f_phone| %>
    <div class="field">
      <p>
        <%= f_phone.label :phone_number %><br />
        <%= f_phone.text_field :phone_number %>
      </p>
    </div>
    <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

When I fill out both form fields and hit "Save Person" I only get `{"name"=>"foo"}` - the phone number seems to vanish.

However, when I change `phones_attributes` to `phones` I get `{"name"=>"foo", "phones"=>{"phone_number"=>"123"}}` (this would however cause problems with the create function.

What's wrong here?

Please note that this question is strongly related to that one: [accepts_nested_attributes_for: What am I doing wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558309/accepts-nested-attributes-for-what-am-i-doing-wrong) as well as to this posting: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-talk/4RF_CFChua0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem. In the view there should be

```
<%= form_for @person, url: people_path do |f| %>
```

Instead of

```
<%= form_for :person, url: people_path do |f| %>
```

@phron said that already here:
[accepts_nested_attributes_for: What am I doing wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558309/accepts-nested-attributes-for-what-am-i-doing-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have @phones defined in the controller:

```
 def new
    @person = Person.new
    @phones = @person.phones.new
 end
```

Comment: do I need an instance variable for phones? this however wouldn't make the controller save the phone number

Comment: If you want your view to have access to it, you need to make the instance variable available in the controller.  When you say `f.fields_for :phones`, that means use the `@phones` instance variable.

Comment: ok, I didn't know that, thank you. However, I think in this case `def new` is not even touched, but `render text: person_params.inspect` wouldn't return the number I entered.

Comment: `def new` is touched when you initiate the object.  But you are correct that you need to load it again from the database when your action gets called.  You didn't indicate which action in your controller is rendering the form in question.

Comment: I guess you're not trying to display current values in the view.  What comes back in `params[]`?

Comment: in principle I try to store values to the database. `render text: person_params.inspect` is just here for debugging. Leaving the code as it is `create` outputs something like `{"name"=>"<some name>"}`, although it *should* also output some values for `phones`.