# rails 4.0 undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, undefined

I have an `Opportunity` model that has `Activity` as a nested resource. on my `opportunities/show` page, I have a list of activities for that opportunity and a form to add new activities. When I click "add activity" I get:

> undefined method `activities' for nil:NilClass

Here is the error source:

```
 # POST /activities.json
  def create
    @activity = @opportunity.activities.new(activity_params)
    if @activity.save
      redirect_to @opportunity, notice: 'Activity has been added'
    else
```

I defined my `Opportunity` model as having many `Activities` and that my Activities `belongs to` an Opportunity. Here are the relevant parts of my `Activity` controller:

```
def create
  @activity = @opportunity.activities.new(activity_params)
  if @activity.save
    redirect_to @opportunity, notice: 'Activity has been added'
  else
    redirect_to @opportunity, alert: 'Unable to add Activty'
  end
end
```

And here is my views/activities/new code

```
<%= form_for ([@opportunity, @opportunity.activities.new]) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Date Assigned" %> <br />
    <%= f.text_field :date_assigned %> 
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Date Due" %> <br />
    <%= f.text_field :date_due %> 
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Description" %> <br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %> 
</div>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label "Status" %> <br />
    <%= f.text_field :status %> 
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Add' %> 
</div>


<% end %>
```

My routes:

```
resources :opportunities do
   resources :activities
end
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `@opportunity` is **undefined**(nil) in the block.

You must get `@opportunity` prior to building activities on it as :

```
@opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])
```

(**Reason** for `:opportunity_id` : Since this is `ActivityController` and your model is nested, by conventional nested **RESTful** resources (as specified in your routes), the parameter is automatically assigned as model_id => `opportunity_id`)

Changed code:

```
def create
  @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])
  @activity = @opportunity.activities.new(activity_params)
  if @activity.save
    redirect_to @opportunity, notice: 'Activity has been added'
  else
```

Also, it is [recommend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954542/1376448) to use `build` instead of `new` while building object for relations.

Comment: Just curious, why do you recommend build instead of new?

Comment: Though, from the comments thread and further exploring, looks like `new` has now the same behavior has `build` since Rails 3.2.13

Comment: That is an old answer, this changed in some version of Rails 3. `build` is now just an alias of `new`
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-6/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb

Comment: @Iceman Yes, just saw that too. Thanks for the tip :) Though, I still prefer to use `build` instead of `new` in my projects; gives intuitiveness of when I am dealing with the relation objects or dealing with models directly; my personal call ;). Good to have an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try using build instead of new.

```
@activities = @oportunities.activities.build(activity_params)
```

That should work

Edit:

You didn't find for @oportunities before the build :P

```
def create   
  @oportunities.find(params[:id])
  @activity = @opportunity.activities.new(activity_params)
  if @activity.save
    redirect_to @opportunity, notice: 'Activity has been added'
  else
    redirect_to @opportunity, alert: 'Unable to add Activty'
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to find for @oportunities before building the association. Edited answer.

Comment: `build` is just an alias of `new`
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-6/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb