# Creating new objects on associations doesn't work any more?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How does it come `current_user.some_assoc.new` doesn't work any more? Therefore `some_assoc.new(:user_id => current_user.id)` works perfectly while in my understanding it should do the same?

I will though get the error message `NoMethodError: undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass` on the `current_user.some_assoc.new` call.

I just found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954469/744230 where the first two calls do not work for me.

**edit:**

I just tried something out and found that `current_user.some_assocs.new` would work if the user model has a `has_many :some_assocs`, while `has_one :some_assoc` will not allow you to create `some_assoc` this way.

Comment: Not really any way to answer this question as asked.

Comment: I don't know how to express it otherwise, sorry. I basically want to use the first syntax to build an object, which doesn't work (I admit this is not a principal issue, but I find the first one much more intuitive and I am also sure it used to work).

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: I get undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass because current_user.some_assoc is obviously nil.