# Rails new/create actions not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my web app each album has many photos and each photo belongs to an album. I have already done the associations along with the new and create actions for photos and I am not getting an error, however, when I go to the albums show actions the newly created photos are not appearing.

View:

```
        <% @photos.each do |x| %>
            <div class="new-photo">
                <%= image_tag x.image, :style => "height:200px; width:200px; border-radius:5px;" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

Albums controller:

```
def show
    @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
    @photos = @album.photos
    @interests = current_user.interests
end
```

Photos controller:

```
def new
    @photo = current_user.photos.new
end

def create
    @photo = current_user.photos.new(photo_params)
    if @photo.save
        redirect_to '/albums'
    else
        render '/photos/new'
    end
end

private
def photo_params
    params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
end
```

Photo Model:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :album
belongs_to :user
```

end

Album model:

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :photos
```

end

Comment: use `build` instead of `new` in your create action. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4954313/build-vs-new-in-rails-3) might help you.

Comment: Still got the same result

Comment: could you past your model code? do you have any validations?

Comment: How do you upload images? params.require(:photo).permit(:image)...what would be values for image param?

Comment: You've double checked the database to be sure your photos are saving and saving to the correct album?

Comment: The value for (:image) is text @MirzaMemic

Comment: when you run this inside console @album = current_user.albums.find(params[:id])
    and then later album.photos...assuming that you have current user what do you get as a result? It looks like your db is empty or not saved...also sedn a vlaues of one text image if possible,

Comment: When I checked the database the photos were saving with valid user__id but the album_id was always nil @MirzaMemic

Comment: When I checked the database the photos were saving with valid user__id but the album_id was always nil @Luke

Answer (score 0):

So it seems that image is created without an album id. Inside new action then album_id should be assigned in order to display photos later with @photos = @album.photos

this line

```
params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
```

should include

```
params.require(:photo).permit(:image, :album_id)
```