# First argument in form cannot contain nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to use Ajax request for creating a new object and this had been working very well. In my view file I used to set `remote: true` option for link_to and everything was fine.

Now I want to render my _form partial once the view file is loaded without a link, but just using a `<%= render 'form' %>`.
I don't understand why I am getting this error. Who can enlighten me what am I doing wrong?

[image]

**views/tasks/index.html**

```
<h3>Tasks database</h3>

<table>
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
<tr class='tasks' id="task_<%= task.id %>">
  <td>
    <%= link_to user_task_path(current_user, task.id), method: :delete,
     data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, remote: true do %>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
    <% end %>

    <a href="#" data-xeditable="true" data-pk="task" data-model='task' data-name='title'
      data-url="/users/<%= current_user.id %>/tasks/<%= task.id %>" data-title="Enter title">
      <i><%= task.title %></i>
    </a>

  </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
<tr>
  <td><%= render 'form' %></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

**controllers/tasks_controller.rb**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authorize, only: [:edit, :new, :destroy]

  def index
    @tasks = current_user.tasks
  end

  def show
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def edit
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def create
    @task = current_user.tasks.new(task_params)
    respond_to do |format|
    if @task.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_tasks_path(current_user) }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.js
    end
  end
 end

  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])

      respond_to do |format|
    if @task.update(task_params)
      format.html { redirect_to user_tasks_path(current_user), notice: 'Post successfully was updated.'}
      format.json { head :no_content }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
 end

  def destroy
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @task.destroy
    respond_to {|format| format.js }
  end

  private

    def task_params
     params.require(:task).permit(:title)
    end
 end
```

**views/tasks/_form.html**

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @task], remote: true  do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: params[:user_id] %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**views/tasks/create.js**

```
$('#new_task').remove();
$('#new_link').show();
$('.tasks').last().after("<%=j render partial: 'task', :locals => { :task => @task } %>");
setXeditable();
```

Here is my **rake routes**
[image]

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty

You are rendering `form` in `index` page and you didn't set `@task` in `index` method.

You should set `@task` in `index` method

```
def index
  @tasks = current_user.tasks
  @task = Task.new
end
```

Comment: It turns out that I simply don't need new action anymore?

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko Yes. you don't need it in your case.

Comment: prefer to use `@task = current_user.tasks.build` it should filled `user_id` in to the `@task` instance

Comment: I'm wondering how does form_for know it should go to create action after submitting information in view file?

Comment: @Зелёный In my opinion there would be no change using `Task.new` and `current_user.tasks.build` as ultimately we need to do the same thing in `create` action. Any reason for this preference?

Comment: @AlexanderShmatko Its a part of Rails magic :) If you look in to the HTML output it generates you will understand better.

Comment: @Зелёный As for as I know .build is no different than .new method.

Comment: [What is the difference between build and new on Rails?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253426/what-is-the-difference-between-build-and-new-on-rails)

Comment: Yes, in `index` action it will not cause any change, whatever we use.

Comment: another way build instance in the  form directly `form_for [current_user, current_user.tasks.build]` instead `form_for [current_user, @task]`

Comment: @Deep I deleted the first line in my **create.js** file and form doesn't disappear anymore after adding an object. And there still is one thing that concerns me. The second line `$('#new_link').show()` rendering the form. But how is it related then? I can't see any `new_link` part in my code o.O Maybe you know?

Comment: I don't think the second line is rendering the `form`, isn't the third line doing that? Did you try removing the second line.

Comment: @Deep You're right. I'm sorry. I removed that line and this is working. Sadly I have another misunderstanding with the third line, but I don't want to bother you. Thanks.