# form_with produces first record as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

comment controller

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_commentable
  before_action :checked_logged_in, only: [ :create]

  def new
    @comment = @commentabl.comments.new
  end

  def create
    @comment = @commentable.comments.new(comment_params) 
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id
    @comment.commenter = current_user.username


    if @comment.blank? || @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Commented was created"
       ActionCable.server.broadcast 'comment_channel',
        commenter: current_user.username,
        comment: @comment.content
      redirect_to @commentable
    else       
       flash[:danger]  = render_to_string(:partial => 'shared/error_form_messaging',
                                          :locals => {obj: @comment}, 
                                          format: :html)
       redirect_to @commentable   
    end
  end
private

  def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content, :commenter, :user_id)
  end
  def load_commentable
    resource, id = request.path.split('/')[1,2]
    @commentable = resource.singularize.classify.constantize.find(id)
  end

  def checked_logged_in
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:danger] = 'please log in to be able to comment'
      redirect_to login_path
    end
  end

end
```

my form for creating a comment:

```
<%= form_with  model:[commentable, commentable.comments.new], :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role:"form"} , local: true do |form| %>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
         <%= form.label :content, 'Comment' %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
         <%= form.text_field :content , class: 'form-control', placeholder: "enter your comment here", autofocus: true %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <%= form.submit 'Comment' , class: ' btn btn-primary' %> 
    </div>
</div>              
<% end %>
```

the form is called in `show.html.erb`

```
<h2 class="text-center">
    Title: <%= @article.title %>
</h2>
<div class="well col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
    <div id="user-info-showpage" align="center">
        Created by: <%= render 'shared/user-info', obj: @article.user %>    
    </div>    
    <h4 class="text-center">
        <strong>Description:</strong>         
    </h4>
    <hr />
    <%= simple_format(@article.description) %>
    <% if @article.categories.any? %>
        <p>Categories: <%= render @article.categories %></p>      
     <% end %>
        <div class="article-actions">  
            <% if logged_in? && (current_user == @article.user || current_user.admin?) %>
                 <%= link_to "Delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete, 
                 data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete the article?"}, 
                 class: 'btn btn-xs btn-danger' %>
                 <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article), class: 'btn btn-xs btn-success'%>
            <%end%> 
            <%= link_to "View All Articles", articles_path  , class: 'btn btn-xs btn-primary'%> 
        </div> 
</div> 
<% if logged_in? %>
    <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <%#= render partial: 'comments/form', :locals => {commentable:   @article} %>   
    </div>
<%end%> 

<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2"> 
     <div id="comments"></div>
     <%= @article.comments.inspect %>
        <% @article.comments.each do |c| %>     
            <div class="well">           
                    <%= c.content %>   by 
                    <%= c.commenter %>           
            </div>
        <%end%>

     <div id="comments"></div>
</div>
```

my result is in view is [image]

Please if more info needed, ask me so I can provide

Note: **I am not sure this empty record is owing to commentable.comments to be nil or I miss something**

I commented render form in show page and now the empty record is gone, so my issue  must be related to form_with

[image]

Comment: Can you show your `show.html.erb` code? By the way, `commentable.comments.new` should be `commentable.comments.build`

Comment: thanks for the response. I tested with the build and get the same result. and I posted whole code for show page. **Is build alias of new?** so they should be the same, should not they?

Comment: why do you need to put `<%= @article.comments.inspect %>` in your form? You can remove it if you don't want to see `#<ActiveRecord...`

Comment: It is for debugging purposes. when I solve the issue, I will delete it.

Comment: @KickButtowski could you share controller's code

Comment: so I still don't understand what your problem is? I think `#<ActiveRecord...` is from `commentable.comments.build` because it is a new comment of current article with id `1`.

Comment: `#<Comment id: nil`... it is clearly just a new comment object and not stored in database yet.

Comment: why is it shown in the view?

Comment: I guess because you have `<%= @article.comments.inspect %>`. Is it shown in the view if you remove that code?

Comment: it is gonne be the same. they are different entities. we better chat somewhere

Comment: @NirajKaushal sorry I missed your comment. done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185703/discussion-between-thanh-and-kick-buttowski).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, you

### Expect:

- in your `articles#show` page to not show the empty `by _________` `<div>` HTML because the `comment` is still built (still in-memory), and not yet saved (not yet in DB).

### Solution 1:

**app/views/articles/show.html.erb**

```
...
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2"> 
  <div id="comments"></div>
    <% @article.comments.each do |c| %>
      <!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
      <% if c.persisted? %>
        <div class="well">           
          <%= c.content %>   by 
          <%= c.commenter %>           
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <%end%>
  <div id="comments"></div>
</div>
...
```

### Solution 2 (better but still is a workaround):

**app/views/comments/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with  model:[commentable, Comment.new(commentable: commentable)], :html => {class: "form-horizontal", role:"form"} , local: true do |form| %>
```

### Explanation:

- The reason the page is displaying an empty `by _________` `<div>` is that because you "built" a new `comment` before `.each` is called. Because they are sharing same memory space, the `build` basically also adds it to the array in-memory. See the following:

  ```
  # rails console
  article = Article.create!
  comment1 = Comment.create!(commentable: article)
  # from here, comment1 is then saved already in the DB

  # now let's see what happens when you use "build" or "new"
  # They have differences, it seem: for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253426/what-is-the-difference-between-build-and-new-on-rails/1253462

  # redefine (to simulate your @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  article = Article.find(article.id)
  comment2 = article.comments.build

  puts article.comments.count
  # SQL: Select count(*) FROM ...
  # => 1

  puts article.comments.size
  # => 2

  # notice how `count` and `size` are different. `count` value is "DB-based" while `size` is "memory-based". This is because `count` is an `ActiveRecord` method while `size` is a delegated `Array` method.

  # now let's simulate your actual problem in the view, where you were looping...
  article.comments.each do |comment|
    puts comment
  end
  # => <Comment id: 1>
  # => <Comment id: nil>

  # notice that you got 2 comments:
  #  one is that which is already persisted in DB
  #  and the other is the "built" one

  # the behaviour above is to be expected because `.each` is a delegated `Array` method 
  # which is agnostic to where its items come from (DB or not)
  ```

This is the reason why in your page, the "built" comment is shown in the page because you are calling

`<%= render partial: 'comments/form', :locals => {commentable:   @article} %>`
... which calls `commentable.comments.build`

**BEFORE** the `<% "article.comments.each do |c| %>`

If this is not clear enough yet, try putting

`<%= render partial: 'comments/form', :locals => {commentable:   @article} %>`

... which calls `commentable.comments.build`

**AFTER** the `<% "article.comments.each do |c| %> ... <% end %>`
... and the `by _________` `<div>` should already not show up.

Comment: if the comment is not being saved in db why is it even shown?

Comment: @KickButtowski if you notice my explanation code above, it's being shown because you "built" a comment of which is rendered into the view in your `.each` loop. Using `comments.build` will build an instance of `Comment` into the array (in-memory). This is by design. You could think of build as if something like the following: `article.comments << Comment.new` (except that it's still in-memory)