# Rails 5 - creating "Comments" for an "Article" with a has_many relationship between them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

My questions is regarding section 6.4 of the official [Rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

I have an **articles** and a **comments** model with a has_many relationship between them. Now, we edit the Article show template (app/views/articles/show.html.erb) to let us make a new comment for each Article:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_with(model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :commenter %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label :body %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(@article) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', articles_path %>
```

Can someone ELI5 the form_with declaration ?

> form_with(model: [ @article, @article.comments.build ], local: true)

I understand that each comment has to be created for a particular article and the description in the guide also mentions that the `form_with` call here uses an array but why do we need to pass an array to model: ? and why do we have two members in the array ? What if we just pass `@article.comments` to the model: ? What is the significance of the `.build` function call as compared to `@article.comments.create` call used in `comments_controller.rb` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rails generates the routes from `form_with`. Let's consider this case:

```
<%= form_with(@article) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

when the article is new, and doesn't exists in database, Rails deduce that route would be:

```
articles_path(@article), action: :create
```

because you are creating a new one.

If article exists in database, Rails generates update route:

```
articles_path(@article), action: :update
```

Consequently, array means, that path will be nested. So, this code:

```
<%= form_with([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
 ...
<% end %>
```

Generates this route, if the comment doesn't exist in database:

```
article_comments_path(@article, @article.comments.build), action: :create
```

Otherwise, route will be:

```
article_comments_path(@article, @comment), action: :update
```

More about difference between `new` and `build`: [What is the difference between build and new on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253426/what-is-the-difference-between-build-and-new-on-rails)

More about comparison of `form_for`, `form_with` and `form_tag` https://m.patrikonrails.com/rails-5-1s-form-with-vs-old-form-helpers-3a5f72a8c78a

Comment: Thanks! You made things a little clearer for me. About `article_comments_path(@article, @article.comments.build)` , what does this mean ? Also, why are you sing form_for in your examples if form_with is the newer standard,  did you mean to use form_with ?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo and should be `form_with`. Thanks. About article_comments_path(@article, @article.comments.build): it will generate path like that: /articles/@article.id/comments (POST request)

Comment: Thank you for this. But I still want to what is the comments in @article.comments.build? Is it referring to the controller or model?